# Fixing previous wiring at switch for recessed lighting

Tags: electrical, switch, recessed-lighting

I moved in to this house and the ceiling fan and recessed lighting worked (we did demo in the master and the lights worked). Painters came in right after that and the lights have never worked since. I figured they loosened a wire wh when they were working (as I knew nothing about switches). I finally checked the switch and everything was tight and the switches work. I have spend TOO much time trying to figure this out. :)

There were dimmers on the light switch and fan switch. I’m assuming this room previous had a light/fan combo. It now has 6 LED recessed lights and a fan. The “light” switch messes with the fan’s speed when we had the dimmers attached. I have both of them on 2 way switches. (The third switch in the box is a three way switch to an outlet across the room.)

I have black piggy backed wires from the big group of black wires going to each of the two pole receptacles to the bottom screws. Both are grounded. Coming from the same 14-3 (I think that’s what’s it’s called, Super green here), the black wire is going in to the top screw on the “fan” switch and the red wire (which is hot too) is going to the top wire on the “light” switch.

The lights don’t turn on. I took the LED lights out and screwed them in to a floor lamp and they turn on. I check the cans and they do not get power. I check the cans in another room the same way and they get power. Who will be my hero and help me figure this craziness out? I know I can call an electrician. But I really want to figure this puzzle out! Thank you!

Comment: Telliing you to hire an electrician is not our format here. :) How deep do you want to get into this?  It sounds like you are at the "pull the cover off, pull the switches out and inspect" stage so far.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the inside of the switch box, with the breaker off of course?